# Parms were split on blanks

Tags: php, ibm-midrange, zend-server

Call PHP from IBM i Server with Zendserver
I sent a few Parms to php script. On one of our machines the parms were split on blanks ?
But why ? They are in Doublequotes ??

```
CALL       PGM(QP2SHELL) +                                
           PARM('/USR/LOCAL/ZENDSVR/BIN/PHP-CLI' +        
           '/www/zendsvr/htdocs/test/t1.php' +    
           'Hallo Test' + 'P2' + 'P3')
```

In PHP the args array contains

```
[0] => /www/zendsvr/htdocs/idsmail/t1.php5
[1] => Hallo
[2] => Test
[3] => P2                            
[4] => P3
```

On other machines the same Program works fine ??

Any ideas ?

Bye jogi

Comment: I don't see any double quotes anywhere in your code... The machine that is behaving differently - any chance it's running a different version of the OS?

Comment: If the 4th line of call statement actually looks like this, then you would have a syntax error, and not get to PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your example looks exactly like your CL code, then you've got too many `+` signs.  In source code, CL commands normally terminate at the end of a line.  If your command continues onto another line you indicate this with a `+` symbol.  In this context it is not a meant as a concatenation operator (which would be `||`).  Spaces suffice to separate the parameters.

You don't need the `+` signs on the 4th line, which would be seen as arithmetic operators.  This should solve your problem:

```
CALL       PGM(QP2SHELL) +                                
           PARM('/USR/LOCAL/ZENDSVR/BIN/PHP-CLI' +        
           '/www/zendsvr/htdocs/test/t1.php' +    
           'Hallo Test'  'P2'  'P3')
```

The keywords PGM and PARM are not required, so personally, I would write it like this:

```
CALL QP2SHELL  ('/USR/LOCAL/ZENDSVR/BIN/PHP-CLI' +        
                '/www/zendsvr/htdocs/test/t1.php' +    
                'Hallo Test' +
                'P2' +
                'P3' +
               )
```